ARIMAX time series with different lengths
I'm building an ARIMAX model with two time series: one has been differenced to make it stationary, while the other is already stationary and has more observations. How can I align these two series with different lengths so they can be used together in an ARIMAX model, and what’s the best approach to handle this in R?

you need use ARMAX model, i.e. without integration, then align the differences and stationary series. you can't selectively apply differencing to elements of the vector of series in standard ARIMA.
